# Does onBeforeRequest in chrome.webRequest fires for DNS request?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dns, webrequest

I want to write a chrome extension/app to log DNS request like A or AAA records that are sent from the client browser when a new page is browsed. Does onBeforeRequest in chrome.webRequest API fires for DNS requests? Is there any api to give access to the DNS requests?

Comment: No, webRequest is related to http and https requests only.

Comment: is it possible to log dns requests at all? any other api/solutoin?